# Hybridauth LinkedIn API - Invalid Token issue

Tags: linkedin-api

I have configured HybirdAuth for social logins as my all other social logins are working but suddenly linkedIn stop working and shows this error.

Original error message: Authentication failed! LinkedIn returned an invalid Token.

I have search and try different methods but nothing worked out.

I have change keys, create new apps, make some changes in the code.

Please help.

Comment: Please attach your linkedin response, this will help other to get the problem.

Comment: Can also be view as below

Array
(
    [errorCode] => 0
    [message] => [unauthorized]. The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. consumerKey: 77zl215zorlwwd
    [requestId] => F20E9JGSY7
    [status] => 401
    [timestamp] => 1439446103300
)

Comment: Array
(
    [errorCode] => 0
    [message] => Could not find person based on: ~
    [requestId] => MJMN4VGFWQ
    [status] => 404
    [timestamp] => 1439445707196
)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using invalid consumer key.

```
[`message] => [unauthorized]. The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. consumerKey: 77zl215zorlwwd`
```

Double check your app settings for consumer key.

Comment: I have doubled checked several times , also create new apps but seems to be same error everytime.